# Is there a GhostDoc like plug-in for CodeRush or ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, coderush, ghostdoc

I have noticed that GhostDoc hasn't been updated in a long while.  So I am curious if there is a plug-in for Resharper or CodeRush that will accomplish the same thing?  Or even if this type of functionality is built in to one of the tools that would be great too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latest version of GhostDoc specifically works with VS 2008.  Not sure what you mean that it hasn't been updated in a long while.  As far as I'm concerned, GhostDoc is the best in-code XML commenter available.  It is customizable, has great language and grammar support.  And it just works.

Is there something specifically that it does not do for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could try my free AtomineerUtils add-in. It's very similar to GhostDoc, but I believe it is more powerful and flexible (e.g. among many advantages: it supports VB, C# C++/CLI, C++, C; both Doxygen and DocXml comment formats; optionally word-wraps comments & doc-comments, is completely configurable, and adds entries for things like exceptions thrown within a method). I'm still actively developing it.

Details & download at [atomineerutils.com](http://atomineerutils.com/).

Comment: Seems like a nice utility, but I really only want something that does documentation. This seems like a kitchen sink utility amiled mostly at C++.

Comment: To generate "external" (HTML or PDF) code documentation you can combine AtomineerUtils with a documentation generation tool (such as Doxygen, Sandcastle, NDoc, etc). These will use the comments generated by AtomineerUtils to generate standalone documentation files. THe advantage of using XmlDoc format is that the documentation will then be available within visual studio (inline in the code itself, and also shown on intellisense tooltips when you hover over function calls, and in places like the object browser). This is more useful than just writing external documentation uninked to the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ReSharper you could always give [StyleCop for ReSharper](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/) a try - it has some of the documentation features of GhostDoc but also a [myriad of other QuickFixes](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Fixes) and formatting options based on the StyleCop ruleset.

Comment: But what does it do? Does this StyleCop for R# generated XML documentation or does it just inform developer that it's missing (likely directly in the code at the beginning of the line)?

Comment: It will generate the documentation stubs (and in some cases fill it out) for you.

Answer (score 1):

GhostDoc is working just fine, so I guess there is no need to be updated (unless some new features will be added). Also, it does not conflict with Resharper in any way (for me, at least).

**Edit:** Since everybody seems to happily use GhostDoc (based on my Google search), I doubt anyone will reinvent the wheel, unless it suffers from the not-invented-here sindrom.

**EDIT** Well, a new version was released: [SubMain acquires GhostDoc, releases new version, integrates it with CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/blog/SubMainAcquiresGhostDocReleasesNewVersionIntegratesItWithCodeItRight.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Like many people, I couldn't live without the [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) plug-in.

Apart from being a great time-saver, if GhostDoc doesn't give a sensible "summary" description for my method, I know I've named the method poorly. To me, that is of great value!

From the new GhostDoc website:

> SubMain [has recently acquired GhostDoc](http://submain.com/blog/SubMainAcquiresGhostDocReleasesNewVersionIntegratesItWithCodeItRight.aspx). We will continue to maintain
>   and distribute the product free of charge. We will be improving GhostDoc
>   and we always welcome the community feedback. If you have ideas, please
>   post them in the [GhostDoc forum](http://submain.com/support/ghostdoc/). Roland Weigelt is the original author
>   of GhostDoc and his web site can be found at http://roland-weigelt.de/

It is still freeware, but with the new advantage of support from a respected commercial development tools company.